# Named pipes msdn sample faulty?

Tags: c#, c++, named-pipes

I'm using this sample exactly (except I changed tchar to char everywhere):
`https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365601%28v=vs.85%29.aspx`

I'm using the following c# code to send a medium sized (=400kb) file to the c++ server:

```
var client = new NamedPipeClientStream(@"SamplePipe");
client.Connect();
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client);

string bla = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Request.txt");
writer.Write(bla);
```

This is the file I'm sending: 
`http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/45745/pg45745.txt`

It **never** sends data beyond this passage: "of us stand as high as a tall man, and a measure four feet from bill to tail. Thur" (around 170kb of 400kb)
(I dont understand where the 'ur' comes from, the next word would be 'There')

The last thing that happens is a WAIT_IO_COMPLETION as far as I can tell and then it just stays forever on the `writer.Write(bla)` line. But this may be circumstancial.
What's going on? I have also tried some of the other samples and they all seem to have problems with larger files.

Comment: If you changed to code to this code ([PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/HVNtxjqy)), does it complete the write process of the entire file? (Used pastebin to not create an answer with code that might not be an answer

Comment: Bernd, no it stops still at the exact same "thur"

Comment: Have you tried setting `AutoFlush = true;` on your `StreamWriter`? Also, after `writer.Write(bla);` try adding `client.WaitForPipeDrain();` and see if it goes through.

Comment: yes, that didnt seem to change anything - if anything it wrote less. The WaitForPipeDrain isnt a boolean is it? it's one active call, so when would i call it? the foreach line approach isnt exactly what I want in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I figured it out:

Your C++ sample has the `PipeTransmissionMode` set to `'Message'` (`PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE` and `PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE`) while your C# `NamedPipeClientStream` is using the `PipeTransmissionMode 'Byte'` by default.

So change `PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE` to `PIPE_TYPE_BYTE` and `PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE` to `PIPE_READMODE_BYTE`.

Check this [CreateNamedPipe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365150%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function page on MSDN for more information to make sure your PipeServer is properly setup.

Comment: hm pretty sure the pipe type for c# is by default "message" and I need it to be message so that I know when it ends, but yeah I can definitely try that later

Comment: Ok maybe you're right, but since both client and server are setup as InOut direction, make sure to set `client.ReadMode = PipeTransmissionMode.Message`. (just in case)